# does my opengl es draw(); call draw objects not currently seen on the screen?

Tags: android, opengl-es

In Android. If im drawing objects off screen, it would be a big performance boost to disable these objects assuming they arent already disabled from being drawn when off screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your question is how to cool the invisible objects. It depends on whether you're using 2d or 3d scene. In 2d it's very simple: everything outside the screen rectangle is culled. While in 3d it is very complex problem and there are tons of different techniques like bsp trees or portal rendering. The key word to google is "object culling".